# Is there a way to proxy a request using Zuul before hitting other Filters?

Tags: servlet-filters, netflix-zuul

I am building a simple API gateway application in which I am proxying my requests to another service using the [Zuul library](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul). Apart from the Zuul library, I am using another library containing a [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which is being hit before the request being proxied by Zuul and this is causing undesired behaviour.

Is there a way to proxy a request using Zuul before hitting other Filters?

I tried to make use of the [pre filter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#zuul-developer-guide-sample-pre-filter) to try to find a way to skip the other library's filter but this still gets executed after the other filter.

Is there a way around this using any configuration from Zuul? The only option which I am thinking of right now is to create a Filter superseding the other library's one in order to bypass the filter or else proxying the request myself without passing through Zuul.